# Fifos in Linux in packet mode

Tags: c, linux, pipe, named-pipes, fifo

I have read the Linux [manpage](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/pipe.2.html) of pipe2, that states that you can use the O_DIRECT flag to create a pipe that performs I/O in packet mode.

I haven't found anything similar for fifos (named pipes) although I have heard that pipes and fifos share a lot of code in Linux, and it could be useful to me in a project (we already pass messages in fifos, but we have to seek for an especial terminator, reading one byte at a time).

Is there anything equivalent to perform fifo I/O in packet mode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `O_*` flags on a file descriptor can usually be changed by `fcntl(fd, F_SETFL, ...)` but in this case I don't think it will work, because of this:

https://lkml.org/lkml/2015/12/15/480

It's a patch that was submitted just 2 weeks ago to support exactly this use case, and the only replies to it have been a couple of build failures from an automated tester.

So you can try fixing that patch and applying it (should be easy - looks like a typo, the `f` should be `filp`)...

or (this is the option I'd prefer) see if your needs can be met by an `AF_UNIX`, `SOCK_SEQPACKET` socket instead of a pipe with this new flag. They're more powerful *and* more portable.

(I assume you already tried passing the `O_DIRECT` to `open` when you open the named pipe, since that's the most obvious thing.)

Answer (score 2):

I'm not able to switch to a socket or message queue, and am stuck with using pipe. But good news, the patch refereed to in user2404501's answer eventually got accepted and is in linux v4.5 and newer. So using fnctl() to set O_DIRECT on a named pipe is valid.

https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/?id=0dbf5f20652108106cb822ad7662c786baaa03ff

Answer (score 1):

Both `pipe` & `fifo` are byte stream, it open a `file descriptor`, then use `read()` and `write()` to do communication.

If u want a `packet` (I am not sure what u mean, I assume you want to read a block of data without determine the boundary by yourself), `POSIX - message queue` might be a good choice. It send / receive data in unit of a message instead of byte by byte.

And you can also set `priority` on the messages which change the order of receiving, if all messages have the same priority (e.g 0), then the send & receive order is the same as FIFO.

If that's what u want, then check `man mq_overview` for details.

Comment: Well, I know about POSIX and System V message queues, but they are not transparent to applications (they can't be opened and used like regular files). Also I was told that POSIX message queues have low default limits of messages and size, so they aren't very useful.

Comment: The limits is low by default, but totally configurable (simply change a file), especially for `privileged process`. Since FIFO is not suitable for concurrent programming, thus it's not proper to have multiple clients, and thus the data should not be that much. Also if u want to exchange data, why need to be opened like regular files...